# Can I use LOS on Samsung S4 Mini GT-I9195I?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, lineageos

I have successfully installed Lineage OS on Samsung S4 Mini GT-I9195, but now I got a GT-I9195I which should be a more advanced model with better CPU. I can't find any reliable informations, if this model is also suitable for Lineage.

Comment: Usually the "plus", "+", "VE" or "Value Edition" are not really upgraded versions but variants that are cheaper for Samsung to manufacture. In case of i9195i you get more CPU cores but each core is a slower than the cores of i9195. Most software not being able to scale up to 4 cores makes the i9195i probably slower in real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serranoveltexx (GT-i9195i, 4G single-SIM, SD410; the "ve" stands for "value edition") is not a part of the official LOS build roster, and likely won't be due to the lower popularity.

There are unofficial builds available at XDA-Developers: [14.1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-mini/orig-development/rom-cyanogenmod-14-1-t3522169), [15.0](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-mini/development/rom-lineageos-15-0-t3708005). Note that you need the packages for your specific variant (marks "ve").

Comment: i9195i seems to work fine with PixelExperience builds. Make sure to install TWRP 3.3.x or later or install will fail. For more info: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-mini/development/rom-pixel-experience-t3870945